# Django - How to use URLconfs with an apps folder?

Tags: python, django, urlconf

I'm following the tutorial on the Django website but I'm trying to expand upon it.  I like the organizational scheme of putting all of your apps in an "apps" folder.  I'm trying to figure out the proper way to include urls.py in order to get everything to link together.

Here's my root urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/', include('apps.polls.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here's my urls.py at apps/polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns=patterns('polls.views',
    (r'^polls/$', 'index'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

What's the correct way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you currently have it set up... the URLs for polls would be:

```
http://your.url.here/polls/polls/235/results/
```

This is probably not what you want.  The `include` function in the `urlpatterns` in the root urls.py file specifies `"polls/"` as a prefix to all `urlpatterns` in the polls app.  Therefore, in the polls/urls.py file, you shouldn't specify the `"polls/"` prefix again as it will cause duplicate prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your Django instances? If you have multiple vhosts configured in Apache then each Django instance in /apps has it's own urls.py.

Comment: Umm...I'm running one django instance in Eclipse...I think.  I don't have any virtual hosts or Apache, just Django in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('polls.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

I guess the polls part is taken care of in the root urlconf